# Ant error: [javac] error: Source option 6 is no longer supported. Use 8 or later

Tags: java, ant

I have a local copy of the repo at https://github.com/dwdyer/zeitgeist which I'm trying to build from. I followed the instructions in the repo's README file to build it using Ant, but got the following errors:

```
    [javac] error: Source option 6 is no longer supported. Use 8 or later.
    [javac] error: Target option 6 is no longer supported. Use 8 or later.
```

Following the README instructions https://github.com/dwdyer/zeitgeist/blob/master/README.txt I run

`ant clean dist`

in project root directory. The build failed with the following console output:

```
ANT_OPTS is set to  -Djava.security.manager=allow
Buildfile: C:\Users\josep\Not_Junk\Temp\zeitgeist-master\build.xml

clean:
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\Users\josep\Not_Junk\Temp\zeitgeist-master\core\build

core:
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\josep\Not_Junk\Temp\zeitgeist-master\core\build\classes\main
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\josep\Not_Junk\Temp\zeitgeist-master\core\build\generated\main
    [javac] Compiling 16 source files to C:\Users\josep\Not_Junk\Temp\zeitgeist-master\core\build\classes\main
    [javac] warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 6
    [javac] error: Source option 6 is no longer supported. Use 8 or later.
    [javac] error: Target option 6 is no longer supported. Use 8 or later.

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\josep\Not_Junk\Temp\zeitgeist-master\build.xml:68: The following error occurred while executing this line:
jar:file:/C:/Users/josep/Not_Junk/Temp/zeitgeist-master/lib/compiletime/uncommons-antlib-0.3.3.jar!/org/uncommons/antlib/antlib.xml:120: The following error occurred while executing this line:
jar:file:/C:/Users/josep/Not_Junk/Temp/zeitgeist-master/lib/compiletime/uncommons-antlib-0.3.3.jar!/org/uncommons/antlib/antlib.xml:83: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 0 seconds
```

java and javac versions are as follows:

```
>java -version
java version "20" 2023-03-21
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 20+36-2344)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20+36-2344, mixed mode, sharing)


>javac -version
javac 20
```

Solutions for similar issues I've seen suggested are to change  block starting `<target name="javac" ...` in the build.xml file. However, https://github.com/dwdyer/zeitgeist/blob/master/build.xml contains no mention of "javac" or "compiler" so if adding a section like this is the solution, I have no idea how to format it.

I haven't used Ant before, so I don't have any familiarity with how the build.xml file should be structured.

Comment: The project hasn't been updated in 10 years and was written for Java 1.6. There is even a bug report about building in 2022 (https://github.com/dwdyer/zeitgeist/issues/3) but with little activity. It seems to use some ant support library (https://github.com/dwdyer/uncommons-antlib), but that one also hasn't been updated in 10 years. This might require some heavy lifting to upgrade it to Java versions 9 and later.

Comment: Your best bet might be to use OpenJDK 1.8 to build and run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to upgrade the uncommons-antlib by changing the source & target in build.xml to 1.8. You might be good to go or you may have to build uncommons-antlib separately first.

```
<javac destdir="./build/classes/main"
       debug="on"
       deprecation="on"
       optimize="on"
       source="1.5"
       target="1.5"
       srcdir="./src/java/main"
       includeantruntime="false">
```

Or you can install an ancient jdk, ie 1.7.

Comment: Thank you. I added the following target to build.xml:
`
<target name="compile">
    <javac destdir="./core/build/classes/main"
    debug="on"
    deprecation="on"
    optimize="on"
    source="1.9"
    target="1.9"
    srcdir="./core/src/java/main"
    includeantruntime="false"/>
  </target>
`

This fixed the reported error. I still had plenty of missing dependencies stopping me, but this totally fixed the issue framed in my initial question